# Visit Last Loaded URL

Tags: webview, xamarin.android, android-webview

I'm making an app in **Xamarin android** where user navigates. The app contains webview. When a user opens webview, url gets loaded and browsing can be done. When he ends the app and opens it again, URL is loaded again instead of viewing last visited URL.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong here.

```
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
        webView.SetWebViewClient(new MyWebClient());
        CookieManager.Instance.SetAcceptCookie(true);
        webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        webView.Settings.SetAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.LoadUrl(getUrl());
        webView.SetPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);


        webView.Settings.SetSupportZoom(true);

    }
    public void saveUrl(String url)
    {
        ISharedPreferences sp = GetSharedPreferences("SP_WEBVIEW_PREFS", FileCreationMode.Private);
        ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = sp.Edit();
        editor.PutString("SAVED_URL", url);
        editor.Commit();
    }
    public String getUrl()
    {

        ISharedPreferences sp = GetSharedPreferences("SP_WEBVIEW_PREFS", FileCreationMode.Private);
        //If you haven't saved the url before, the default value will be google's page
        return sp.GetString("SAVED_URL", "http://google.com");

    }
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url)
    {
        this.onPageFinished(view, url);
        saveUrl(url);

    }
}

internal class MyWebClient : WebViewClient
{
    public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
    {
        view.LoadUrl(url);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to write a proper title, and fix the question, what is "URL is loaded again" -- do you mean it starts from the beginning?

Comment: yes it starts from beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have placed `onPageFinished` method in an Activity. It should be overridden in `MyWebClient` class as below:

```
internal class MyWebClient : WebViewClient 
{ 
     public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url) 
     { 
           view.LoadUrl(url); 
           return false; 
     } 


     public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
     { 
           base.OnPageFinished(view, url); 

           //Save the url here. 
           //This method itself gives you the last url loaded as it's url Parameter.
           ISharedPreferences sp = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("SP_WEBVIEW_PREFS", FileCreationMode.Private);
           ISharedPreferencesEditor editor = sp.Edit();
           editor.PutString("SAVED_URL", url);
           editor.Commit().
     }
}
```

This method will be automatically called when URL finished loading and then you will store your loaded URL in this method.

Comment: I don't think you should use saveUrl method written in your activity. You should better move it's code to OnPageFinished method itself and save the last url from there. You can use webView.Url if you wish to but this same will be given as part of the OnPageFinished method param. Better you remove saveUrl method from activity and check my edited answer.